# Is there a decent image uploading library for Rails 3?

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tried Paperclip and Dragonfly and found them to be difficult to use if your needs are even slightly different than the poorly written examples, and the docs lack greatly.

Is there such a thing as a easy-to-use image uploading library for rails?

Comment: If there's a specific problem you're having with Paperclip you could probably ask about it here and get some help...

Comment: I will if I need to stick with one, I just wanted to see what else is out there and to just vent a little :)

Comment: Understood, been there. ;) Maybe I'll check out Carrierwave (HVAC?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[yup](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads) - [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Comment: Thanks for the input i decided to skip the rails image gems and just handle the uploads manually and use Rmagick. All the libraries lacked at least one feature that I needed and complicated things. What I was looking for is database storage(or at least be able to restrict access to logged in users without needing to write a rack auth system), the ability to mark images as public as well, and the ability to resize on the fly and get image information without needing to create db fields for it. Nothing seemed to fit my criteria, which means more work than rolling my own library on top of Rmagick